# Stretching a column so that table fills up specified area

Tags: tables, plain-tex, columns

Using plain TeX how can I make column 2 in the following table take up the remaining space to `.5\hsize` while preserving the other columns' property to have a variable width dependent on their contents?

```
\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
\halign to.5\hsize{
   \vrule#\strut&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#&
   \enskip#\enskip\hfil&
   \vrule#&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf ID\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Description\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Quantity\enskip\hfil&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1&
   &Blah-blah-blah&
   &100~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &100&
   &Blah-blah&
   &10~000~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &10~000&
   &Blah&
   &100~000~000~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}}
\end
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The trick here is to use tabskip glue so the table stretches but use a spanning cell over that glue for the heading so you can create a box of the correct width to centre the heading (which means you have to put the rule back in by hand)

```
\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
\halign to.5\hsize{
   \vrule#\strut&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#&
   \enskip#\enskip\hfil\tabskip0pt plus 1fil&
   \vrule#\tabskip0pt&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf ID\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\span\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Description\enskip\hfil\vrule
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Quantity\enskip\hfil&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1&
   &Blah-blah-blah&
   &100~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &100&
   &Blah-blah&
   &10~000~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &10~000&
   &Blah&
   &100~000~000~pcs&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}}
\end
```